# Azure function blob BlobPath to lowercase

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts
(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "products/{prod}/all")] HttpRequest req,
  [Blob("%prodPath%", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream myBlobRead,
   ILogger log, string prod)
 {
     var result = await _function.get(myBlobRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
     return result;
 }
)
```

The blob reads the file path from config json file.
Inside the config json file, there is a variable and a value like this:

```
"prodPath": "products/{prod}-all.csv"
```

if the user do a get request like this => www.xxx.com/api/products/table/all

everything is fine because the blob file name called table-all.csv

but if the user tries to do a get request like this => www.xxx.com/api/products/Table/all, its will fail becuase the name does'nt match.

Can you please help me with that?

I tried to change the variable in the config file to

```
[tolower("prodPath")]: "products/{prod}-all.csv"
```

but same problem.

How to change the prod to lowercase ?

Thank you

Comment: What if we set Route in lower case? `Route = "products/{prod}/all".ToLower()`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar i got this error when trying to do as you mentioned => Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type API  HttpTrigger.cs 51 Active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may suggest using the runtime binding technique ([article for c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime) and [c# script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#binding-at-runtime)). The idea is that instead of using the blog attribute you use the `IBinder` parameter and then invoke this binding in your function body. Obviously, you can now evaluate any parameter you want. Note, that you should remove the expression from the json file if you use this technique.

Here is a sample from MSDN combined with bit of your code:

```cs
public static class IBinderExample
{
    [FunctionName("CreateBlobUsingBinder")]
    public static void Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "products/{prod}/all")] HttpRequest req,
        IBinder binder)
    {
        var prodPath = $"products/{prod}-all.csv".ToLower();
        // provide connection string and optionally change TextWriter to whatever you need
        using (var writer = binder.Bind<TextWriter>(new BlobAttribute(
                   prodPath, FileAccess.Write)))
        {
            writer.Write("Hello World!");
        };
    }
}
```